# MongoDB service cannot be found in service list

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have following the instruction from this link
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

And when I'm going to

```
sudo service mongod start
```

it's shown as unrecognized service

I have known that I may need to use mongodb instead of mongod, but it's the same.

Then I have checked all services list by

```
service --status-all
```

There's no mongodb-related service in the list

I have reinstall it again and it's the same. I have also searched through the internet and I cannot find the solution. I install on Windows's ubuntu bash. I have reinstall bash once before this issue (14.04 to 16.04). Last time I installed it before I reinstalled bash it work just fine.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I don't know the reason and solution but you can check the status of mongo itself by this command:

```
sudo service mongod status
```

You may see something like this output:

```
root@lab# service mongod status
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-04-06 09:47:57 BST; 1min 31s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 5973 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─5973 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
```